# Delete all products and reset their Ids with least queries as possible

Tags: magento-1.9, products, delete

Can somebody suggest an intermediate way to delete all products in magento and reset their table's increment id to 1 without using multiple "truncate" queries found when Googling ?

Magento version ce-1.9.x

Answer (score 0):

to delete all the products, Create a file `DeleteProduct.php` inside your magento root folder and write the below code in that file and then execute it with below URL http://www.yourdomain.com/DeleteProduct.php 
try the below code :

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
           ->getCollection();
foreach($productCollection as $_product)
{
    $productID = $_product->getId();

    try {
        Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productID)->delete(); // this will delete product
    } catch (Exception $exception){
        var_dump($exception);
        die('Exception Thrown');
    }
```

Comment: `@Manashvi birla` as I said, I also want to reset the product's table auto-increment id to 1 along with deleting products.

Comment: u'll have to manually set the auto-increment like this `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`